# Clang Formatter multiline formatting config error

Tags: c++, formatting, clang-format

I'm having a problem with how vscode formats my code

The formatting i want:

`std::cout << std::endl << "Something";`

The formatting i get:

```
std::cout << std::endl
          << "Something";
```

My current config:

`"C_Cpp.clang_format_fallbackStyle": "{ BasedOnStyle: Google, IndentWidth: 4, ColumnLimit: 0}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an interaction between `ColumnLimit: 0` and the `<<` operator. I verified this with `clang-format` 6.0.0. Using the [configurator](https://zed0.co.uk/clang-format-configurator/), I can verify this defect first appeared at version 3.6.0, and is there through 10.0.0, so this has been there awhile.

Interestingly, even `>>` works correctly, it's just the `<<` operator which does this.

I don't see any good workarounds - you're left with:

- Live with it.
- Set the ColumnLimit to something else.
- Uglify your code with `operator<<` instead of just `<<`. For example, you'd use something like `std::cout.operator<<(std::endl).operator<<("Something")`.